# Windows Phone equivalent of Badge Icon

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

What are some ways to show either notificationn count or the existence of new unread messages in Windows Phone. 
Like in iOS we use the badge icon.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 you can add Badges to your live tiles:

> A notification badge conveys summary or status information specific to your app. They can be numeric (1-99) or one of a set of system-provided glyphs. Examples of information best conveyed through a badge include network connection status in an online game, user status in a messaging app, number of unread mails in a mail app, and number of new posts in a social media app. Badges can be displayed on all tile sizes. On Windows, they appear in the lower-right corner of the tile (lower-left corner on a computer set to a right-to-left (RTL) language). On Windows Phone 8.1, they appear in the upper-right corner of the tile (upper-left corner on a computer set to a right-to-left (RTL) language).

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779719.aspx